# AngularJS Error: ng:areq Bad Argument while using controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a beginner with AngularJs and I am trying to use controller while creating a simple application. However I am getting an Error and I can't quite figure it out

> Error: ng:areq Bad Argument. Argument 'languages' is not a function, got undefined

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>Angular JS | Controllers</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../resources/js/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        (function(angular){
            var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
            myApp.controller = ('languages', function($scope){
                $scope.myFavLanguage = 'None';
            });
        })(window.angular);


    </script>
</head>
<body >

    <div ng-controller="languages">
        Select your favourite langauge:
        <button>ReactJS</button>
        <button>PHP</button>
        <button>JavaScript</button>
        <button>C++</button>

        <p>Your favourite language is {{myFavLanguage}}</p>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

I have searched over the internet and gone through a few questions on stackoverflow and could'nt get any of them to solve my problem.
These are the ones that I have visited along with a few others. Kindly visit these before marking it as duplicate because it isn't:

[Angularjs bad argument ng:areq error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36110934/angularjs-bad-argument-ngareq-error)

[Angularjs: Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'HomeController' is not a function, got undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895235/angularjs-error-ngareq-argument-homecontroller-is-not-a-function-got-und)

[Argument ... is not a function, got undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15734757/argument-is-not-a-function-got-undefined)

Thanks for any help

Comment: @Rakeschand: I included the same link in my question if you notice. and I mentioned that it did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To define a controller, use the `controller()` method.

```
myApp.controller = ('languages', function($scope){
                 ^
```

Remove the `=` from this.

```
myApp.controller('languages', function($scope) {
```

Check [Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) for more information.

I'll suggest you to use [*min-safe* syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32390338/why-we-inject-our-dependencies-two-times-in-angularjs).

```
myApp.controller('languages', [$scope, function ('$scope') {

}]);
```

Comment: Silly mistake made me search all over the internet, Still couldnt solvet the problem. Thanks. and yeah I was using the min-safe syntax only. Removed it to just to check